# C++ Corrupted heap without using pointers or arrays

Tags: c++, exception, cin, heap-corruption, buffer-overrun

I'm developing a C++ console application to dynamically load a DLL.

The application can successfully invoke one of the DLL's functions. But, at the end of the execution, a corrupted heap exception is thrown. The specific value is:

```
Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.
```

I wonder why... Here the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

typedef DOUBLE(CALLBACK* DllFunc)(DOUBLE, DOUBLE);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    HINSTANCE hDLL;               // Handle to DLL
    DllFunc dllFunc1;
    DOUBLE p1 = 2.0, p2 = 4.0, r;
    wstring dllName;
    string functionName;

    cout << "Insert the dll name: " << endl;
    getline(wcin, dllName);
    cout << "Insert the function name:" << endl;
    getline(cin, functionName);

    cout << "Insert the first value: " << endl;
    cin >> p1;
    cout << "Insert the second value" << endl;
    cin >> p2;

    hDLL = LoadLibrary(dllName.c_str());
    if (hDLL != NULL)
    {
        cout <<  "DLL loaded: " << hDLL << endl;
        functionName = "?" + functionName + "@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z";
        dllFunc1 = (DllFunc)GetProcAddress(hDLL, functionName.c_str());
        if (!dllFunc1)
        {
            // handle the error
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
            cout << "Function not found!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // call the function
            r = dllFunc1(p1, p2);
            cout << "The result is: " << r << endl;
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        }               
    }
    else {
        cout << "Dll not found" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Press any key to exit." << endl;
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know where it could be the problem: if the library is correctly loaded, I free it; there aren't pointers and I'm not using any buffer...

Any idea? The exception occurs only when the execution reaches the last closed curly brace...

Comment: You're interchangeably using widechar and non-widechar versions, is that the intended use you wanted?

Comment: LoadLibrary need a LPCWSTR parameter, while GetProcAddress need a LPCSTR parameter... So I have to use both widechar and non-widechar versions of strings.
By the way, if I remove the `cin, wcin, getline` and i hard code the string, the problem persists.

Comment: Looks fishy 'functionName = "?" + functionName + "@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z";'

Comment: Post the code of the function you're calling.

Comment: @Prakash That's the decorated form of `public: static double __cdecl MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::functionName(double, double)`.

Comment: the message says that this is stack not heap damage, probably the wrong calling convention as mark points out

Comment: @molbdnilo I think Prakash is referring to assigning a string to itself (though I'd have thought the entire construct would fail due to concatenating a const char* then a string).

Comment: "stack-based buffer overrun" would indicate stack corruption, not heap corruption

Answer (score 2):

This seems more like a stack problem (which may be impacting the error reporting).  Is your calling convention correct?  CALLBACK might be `__stdcall` while the decoration seems to indicate `__cdecl`

Comment: Actually... I followed the msdn tutorial and it uses CALLBACK * instead of `__stdcall`.. I've never used explicitly the `__cdecl` function...
By the way, i solved the problem by wrapping everything inside a function. By doing so, the compiler should allocate everything into the stack every time the function is called, and deallocate everything when the function execution finished. Doing so, the errors and the exception disappear and the program runs without problems.

Comment: friendly warning... it sounds like you may have only masked the problem.  note: it's not clear from your question or comment if you created the DLL or not, but the use of __stdcall versus __cdecl depends ONLY on which calling convention the library is using.  simply put, they must match.